# "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in the middle of sending data

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

This socket communication is not my specialty but I need it to perform my hardware in the loop. I've got all my inputs in excel and I send each row separately to the client and the client predicts the output using ML. The problem is in the middle of sending the data the connection is cut or something and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "K:\BachelorThesis\code testing\client.py", line 20, in <module>
msg = s.recv(64)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The server's code is:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler_ti = MinMaxScaler()
test_inputs = []
test_inputs = np.array(test_inputs)
temp_in = pd.read_excel(r'K:\BachelorThesis\Data\Newtesting\testing_in.xlsx')
test_inputs = temp_in.to_numpy()
rows = test_inputs.shape[0]
scaler_ti.fit(test_inputs)
normalized_test_inputs = scaler_ti.transform(test_inputs)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

while True:

    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
    strg = normalized_test_inputs
    temp = strg.tobytes()
    clientsocket.send(temp)
    clientsocket.close()
```

The client's code is:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randint

final = []
final = np.array(final)
modelLSTM = load_model('K:\BachelorThesis\code testing\TireForces.LSTM/LSTM_model.h5')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(64)
    out = np.frombuffer(msg)
    out = out.reshape(1,8)
    out = out.reshape(1,1,8)
    prediction = modelLSTM.predict(out)
    #inverse = scaler_ti.inverse_transform(prediction.reshape(1,8))
    #print(prediction)
    #print(inverse)
    #final = np.vstack(inverse) 
    print(out)
    if len(msg) <= 0:
        break
#print (final)
```

Comment: The server is closing the connection after sending 1 message.  The client is calling `recv()` in a loop until a read is no longer possible. So, why wouldn't you expect `recv()` to report an error? The client is expecting 64 bytes per iteration, how many bytes is the server actually sending?

Comment: when I comment the line where I predict using ML, it receives all the data from the server without any error